# App is not showing in list

Tags: android, image, gallery, chat, whatsapp

When I try to change wallpaper in whatsapp chat, a pop up comes to select between "Android System" or "whatsapp".
My app is showing in Android system list, But in HTC phones no "Android System" option is there.Only Gallery option is there so I am not able to show my app in the list.

I have used following intent filters in my manifest

```
 <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_GALLERY"/>


            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Should I add any other category also?
Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```